# JQuery 1.9.0 minified can't select the text or value from a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following list:

```
<select name="formulas">
  <option value="1" >Lorenz</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Lorenz advanced</option>
  <option value="3" >Body Mass Indice</option>
  <option value="4">Pende</option>
  <option value="5">Broca</option>
</select>
```

Which I try to access with the following method I wrote and in which I use JQuery 1.9.0

```
function calc()
{
    var method = $("#formulas option:selected").text();
    alert(method);

    var number = $("#formulas option:selected").val();
    alert(number);
}
```

Which return in order a empty string and `undefined`, I know there are multiple questions regarding this topic on Stack Overflow but I've tried them all and nothing works.

JQuery works I used it in other methods to append some text to a div.

Does anyone have a ideea on how to get this to work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're selecting your select by id but it has only a name. Change

```
$("#formulas option:selected")
```

to

```
$("select[name=formulas] option:selected")
```

Or, better, give it also an id :

```
<select id=formulas name="formulas">
```

Comment: Thanks I just saw it myself as the question was added, I'll add a id and do it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

you have use 'formulas' as name

```
 <select name="formulas">
```

and using jquery select as id

$("#formulas option:selected").text();

give select id="formulas", it will work.